# Left my Facebook logged in - what could my employer see?

Tags: facebook

I left my Facebook logged in on my work computer (I help with social media and am an admin). I closed the tab without logging out and it was only when I went to go back onto Facebook again that it was already signed in. Will my manager be able to see conversations even if the tab is closed?

Comment: Do you and your manager share a login account on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

Without any traffic to the computer, there would be nothing to "see".

All that occurred was that a special key (and "authentication token") was left on the computer, so that when you visited Facebook again, it logged you in without you needing to enter your password again.

Comment: nitpick: What if everyone shared a desktop login account? The next person logging in could just open facebook and realize that the previous one was logged in.

Comment: @Limit "Will my manager be able to see conversations even if the tab is closed?" -- that's no the type of question you ask when the concern is a shared device, let alone a shared account.

Comment: Fair point. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing they could potentially see in the network traffic is that you were connected to Facebook all day during work hours.

However, you said it was a **work computer**. In that case all bets are off. There is the potential of on-machine monitoring utilities that could see and capture everything you have ever done.

Comment: How much traffic will there be from a closed tab?

Comment: @schroeder - You're limiting your view to a snapshot in time. Potentially the entire historic netflow is available.

Comment: The scope of the *question* is after the tab is closed.

Comment: @schroeder - Oh dear! I guess I considered an aspect you didn't. We'll just have to disagree.

Comment: What aspect? We can't agree or disagree if we can't agree on context? Where would the traffic come from?